# Convert a list into a PCollection

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, dataflow

I currently have a `DoFn` that looks at a bucket and looks at all the files within that bucket and dir prefix. This `DoFn` returns a list instead of a `PCollection`. How would I convert this list into a `PCollection` that can be consumed by the `DoFn` `ConvertFileNames`?

```
  # List all the files within a subdir 
  class ListBlobs(beam.DoFn):
    def start_bundle(self):
      self.storage_client = storage.Client()

    def process(self, prefix):
      bucket = self.storage_client.bucket('xxx')
      return list(self.bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix))

  # Convert Blobs into filenames as patterns
  class ConvertFileNames(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, blob):
      return 'gs://' + blob.bucket.name + blob.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [beam documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#core-beam-transforms), a Beam DoFn's process method returns an iterable of elements to place into the downstream PCollection. So, in your example, if I had a PCollection of prefixes, call it `prefix_pcoll`, then I could write

```
blobs_pcoll = prefix_pcoll | beam.ParDo(ListBlobs())
```

and `blobs_pcoll` will contain the list of blobs with this prefix (namely, the concatination of `list(self.bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix))` over all prefixes). You could then write

```
converted = blobs_pcoll | beam.ParDo(ConvertFileNames())
```

you could also write

```
converted = blobs_pcoll | beam.Map(
    lambda blob: 'gs://' + blob.bucket.name + blob.name)
```

You may also want to look into [apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchAll](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html#apache_beam.io.fileio.MatchAll).